# Applying a function to sub-matrices within a larger matrix

Tags: r

So I have a 1256 by 5 matrix.

```
> head(retmatx12.30.3)
              AMT          HON            KO
[1,] -0.006673489 -0.001292867 -0.0033654493
[2,]  0.004447249  0.002848406  0.0082009877
[3,]  0.001789891  0.002754232 -0.0035886573
[4,] -0.003479321  0.002231823  0.0024011113
[5,] -0.006605786  0.015159190 -0.0002394852
[6,] -0.002375004 -0.008267790 -0.0100625938
              NEM         NVAX
[1,] -0.034023392 -0.023255737
[2,]  0.016436786  0.007936468
[3,]  0.009529404  0.031496102
[4,]  0.046052588  0.007633549
[5,] -0.031446425  0.037878788
[6,] -0.001694084  0.036496350
```

I want to apply a function I've made to rows 1-126, then 2-127, and so on. The function is a block of matrix algebra that uses a matrix and a few vectors. Is it wise to somehow break the larger matrix into 1,131 126 by 5 matrices, and apply the function over each (hopefully at once). Or, some sort of application of apply?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual numbers in the matrix are immaterial, so I'll use much smaller data to demonstrate one method, and a simple function to demonstrate the rolling calculation:

```r
m <- matrix(1:24, nrow=8)
somefunc <- function(x) x %*% seq(ncol(x))
wid <- 4 # 126

somefunc(m[1:4,])
#      [,1]
# [1,]   70
# [2,]   76
# [3,]   82
# [4,]   88

somefunc(m[2:5,])
#      [,1]
# [1,]   76
# [2,]   82
# [3,]   88
# [4,]   94
```

The actual rolling work:

```r
lapply(seq(nrow(m) - wid + 1), function(i) somefunc(m[i - 1 + seq(wid),]))
# [[1]]
#      [,1]
# [1,]   70
# [2,]   76
# [3,]   82
# [4,]   88
# [[2]]
#      [,1]
# [1,]   76
# [2,]   82
# [3,]   88
# [4,]   94
# [[3]]
#      [,1]
# [1,]   82
# [2,]   88
# [3,]   94
# [4,]  100
# [[4]]
#      [,1]
# [1,]   88
# [2,]   94
# [3,]  100
# [4,]  106
# [[5]]
#      [,1]
# [1,]   94
# [2,]  100
# [3,]  106
# [4,]  112
```

where the first element of the output is from rows 1-4, then 2-5, then 2-6, etc.